# Proportion of poor

Tags: r, survey

I’m trying to calculate a proportion of poor using the survey package.
So I create a subset with the variable of the total of population (one) and called n (I’m not sure if it’s the right way to do that).
So, I have:

```
str(base2015$q)
 num [1:117939] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
str(base2015$one)
 int [1:117939] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

and a categoric variable region. (y is my svydesign)
I tried to use the svyratio function like that, but he give me the result for all dataset, and I want by subgroup (region). In deed I want this for each region (see the image)
[proportion of poor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkqmT.png)

```
svyratio(numerator=~q, 
         ~one, 
         design = y, separate=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE, 
         formula, covmat=FALSE, deff=FALSE)
```

I also tried create a subset using the population, and then use the svyby:

```
n <- subset( y , one == 1 )
View(n)
svyby( ~ q , ~ region , n , vartype=c("se","ci","cv"), svytotal )
svyby( ~ q , ~ region , n , vartype=c("se","ci","cv"), svymean )
  region  q  se ci_l ci_u  cv
1      1 NA NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
2      2 NA NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3      3 NA NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
4      4 NA NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
5      5 NA NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

He give me this. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The `NA/NaN` values are a likely result of missing values in your data. To confirm this, you could use `nonMissDF = na.omit(DF)` to exclude missing data and try your function again. If it is confirmed that you face missing data  I suggest to explore methods for imputation of missing data in survey analysis

Comment: Thanks @Osssan. 
the new nonMissDF works well. And I can't do imputation of missing data, because the brazilian institute of geography and statistics (ibge) already did it. So I guess I can't. 
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data(scd)

scddes<-svydesign(data=scd, prob=~1, id=~ambulance, strata=~ESA,nest=TRUE, fpc=rep(5,6))

svyby( ~ alive , denominator = ~ arrests , by = ~ ambulance , scddes , svyratio )

# which missings do you want to remove?  read `?svyby`
svyby( ~ alive , denominator = ~ arrests , by = ~ ambulance , scddes , svyratio , na.rm = TRUE , na.rm.by = TRUE , na.rm.all = TRUE )
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Damico
Help me a lot